# Writing big data with one core in a file reading that file in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi

I am working on a CFD code which is written in Fortran 90. I am trying to make some part of the code to run in parallel and to do that I have to produce a single file of mesh data then read that file with MPI_READ command with multiple cores.

The information that I am writing is structured like `d(id)%nc(3), d(id)%ncg(3,6)`, and ... . `d` refers to one element informations which includes integer and real variables. I want the information of elements to be distributed between multiple cores by parallel reading of the text file that I have already created with one core. As you know, to read a file with MPI_READ_FILE command, a displacement has to be defined for each core to get access to related part of the file, therefore when I am creating the file with one core I have to write the informations in a way that I can count each byte so I could define the displacement for MPI read afterward. Has anyone had any experience in this?

Another problem that I have is that I want to create the file in my PC then transfer it to a cluster. So my code needs to be machine independent so I think I cannot use Binary format or can I?

I am quite new with I/O stuff so If you could introduce me a reference to study I would appreciate.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions is an unreadable wall of text and some formatting is necessary. The question should contain more illustrative code. See also [mcve]. Also, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is very likely too broad for this site. The questions here should be fairly specific. Asking for references and tutorials is off-topic here. And you can and should use binary. You just have to know what you are doing. Everything is littleendian and compatible these days anyway :(

Comment: Hi Ahmed!
First of all, you have 2 questions there:
1. How to read file in parallel.
2. How to upload file.
Answering your first question: reading a file is not bound by CPU, but is bound by I/O, so multiple cores will not make file load faster. To process the file faster, read it into your memory and then use multiple cores for faster processing.